# Hibernate search failover arhitecture

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

We are using the following technology stack : hibernate search latest version (4.1), hibernate core, Mysql tables with InnoDB, Tomcat app.

Our application is reading data from some web page and update index once per day. Index update is not missing critical operation (update can fail and we will just wait for next day). But index search must be always available and content must be sync between different nodes. Index is relative small (50mb).

Any idea how we could do fail-over architecture? Our first idea is to always update index on first node and replicate changes on other nodes. But we have no clue how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Regards,
  Matic

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated the Master/Slave setups Hibernate Search provides? There are multiple technology stacks to chose from, eg JMS or JGroups.